# Filter gets executed even if pattern does not match, Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

The current security configuration I'm using:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

/**
 * Default order of 3 as per Spring documentation.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableResourceServer
public static class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    private final TokenStore tokenStore;

    @Autowired
    public OAuth2SecurityConfiguration(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        this.tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.apply(CommonSecurityConfiguration
                .commonSecurityConfiguration())
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class SecretAuthSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private JPAAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationProvider(JPAAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<Filter> secretFilterRegistrationBean() {
        var filterRegistrationBean =
                new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

        filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(
                new SecretFilter();
        return filterRegistrationBean;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/resource1/api/**", "/resource2/api/**")
            .and()
                .addFilterAfter(this.secretFilterRegistrationBean().getFilter(),
                        LogoutFilter.class)
            .apply(CommonSecurityConfiguration
                    .commonSecurityConfiguration());
    }

}

public static class CommonSecurityConfiguration
        extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<CommonSecurityConfiguration, HttpSecurity> {

    @Override
    public void init(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
            .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }

    public static CommonSecurityConfiguration commonSecurityConfiguration() {
        return new CommonSecurityConfiguration();
    }

}

}
```

I'm pretty new to Spring Security and my goal is to build an application that allows different types of authentications for different paths within my application.

As far as I understood from articles and Spring documentation, you have a lot of flexibility in managing your filter chains, using ANT matchers and things alike.

In the code snippet above I tried to configure 2 filter chains - each one corresponds to a type of authentication:

1. OAuth2, token-based security configuration - described in the static class `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration` - where I used the annotation `@EnableResourceServer`, which automatically adds the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter` to a new filter chain. As per Spring documentation about `@EnableResourceServer`:

> The annotation creates a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter with a hard-coded Order (of 3).

2. A custom authentication type, which is based on a custom filter. What this filter does? It checks a header from the incoming request and it verifies if there is a trusted secret within that header, nothing too special. Here is the core of the filter:

```
public class SecretFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                    FilterChain filterChain)
                                    throws IOException, ServletException {

        log.info("Inside SecretFilter.");

        String secret = this.resolveSecret(httpServletRequest);
        if (secret.isValid()) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(null, null, null));
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        /**
         * Clearing the security context after the request is made.
         */
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
}
```

The resulted filter chains:

```
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain: Creating filter chain:a OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/resource1/api/star.star'], Ant [pattern='/resource2/api/star.star']]]
 - WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
 - SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
 - HeaderWriterFilter
 - CorsFilter
 - LogoutFilter
 - SecretFilter     <------- here is my filter
 - RequestCacheAwareFilter
 - SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
 - AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
 - SessionManagementFilter
 - ExceptionTranslationFilter
```

```
o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher
 - WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
 - SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
 - HeaderWriterFilter
 - CorsFilter
 - LogoutFilter
 - OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
 - RequestCacheAwareFilter
 - SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
 - AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
 - SessionManagementFilter
 - ExceptionTranslationFilter
 - FilterSecurityInterceptor
```

The static configuration class that should handle this type of authentication have been marked with `@Order(1)` annotation, because I want requests to pass first through the filter chain with the custom filter, otherwise, if requests are not intended to the specified paths, like `/resource1/api/**`, then pass through the OAuth filter chain.

When I do a normal request to a path `/resource1/api/X` for example, everything goes well, and the filter chain gets executed. But when a request on a path other than those specified above comes in, the console shows me this:

```
2020-09-22 01:00:03.698 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.698 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.698 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.698 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CorsFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.703 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.703 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.715 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.715 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.715 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.715 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.715 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.716 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2020-09-22 01:00:03.717 DEBUG 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /profile/?date=2020-09-21T22:00:03Z reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2020-09-22 01:00:03.718  INFO 928 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] c.s.p.s.filters.SecretFilter             : Inside SecretFilter.
```

Why the SecretFilter gets executed at the end of the OAuth filter chain? It is not annotated with `@Order` annotation or anything else. My path should not be matched, so the filter chain that contains the filter should not get fired. It looks all so clear, but it is this little thing that I cannot get.

My intuition says that the filter gets registered and placed somehow with the default `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` order and it is executed after the `FilterChainProxy` finishes its job with the current multiplexed chain.

Any help or references to read more about it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Because the filter is executed twice. First as part of the regular filter chain, second as part of the security chain. The first will always execute. Why the `FilterREgistrationBean` just ditch it and instead use `new RegistrationFilter()` in your Spring Security config instead of `his.secretFilterRegistrationBean().getFilter()`. And remove the `FilterRegistrationBean` bean method.

Comment: This solved my problem. I removed the bean, as you said,  and used the `new` operator to add my filter in the chain. Many thanks, but I'm still not satisfied with my knowledge. What's the difference between the regular filter chain and the security chain?

Comment: The regular filter chain is the chain as available from the servlet container. The Spring Security filterchain is, from the pov of the servlet container a single filter (the `FilterChainProxy` to be presice) which delegates to a list of filters. The later is the security filter chain.

Comment: So, in a regular application that uses Spring Security, when a request is coming, both Regular filter chain and Security chain come into action? And there will always exist a Security filter chain? (for example if I hadn't configured any chains at all, there should exist only the Regular filter chain, right?)

Comment: The Spring Security part is also part of the regular chain but it is delegating to a list of filters. This is so that Spring Security can better manage the filters being invoked (and to apply more sophisticated rules to them).